# I deleted my Google App script by accident, can I restore it?

Tags: google-apps-script

I deleted all project in Google App script, I don't know how to restore, it took me more than a month to write it. Is there any way to restore it?

Comment: Had you ever made a copy of the container?

Comment: Did you know that you can save copies of the scripts and restore them with Apps Script API?

Comment: I don't have any backup, i made copy sometime, but I stored backup in same project, what I have to do now :(((

Comment: No I don't know that , Can I restore my script under this circumstances

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: @Cooper I restored it , I contact google support and them help me to retrieve it . Thank you for your time <3

Comment: It make sense to update the question and to show what you did step by step to restore the file.

Comment: On Stack Overflow you are welcome to create an answer to your own question by clicking on the blue "Post Your Answer" button. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). You can even mark your own answer as the "accepted" answer if you want to.

Comment: Just to add: It is always worth checking in Google Drive > Trash. No guarantees, but worth a look.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to restore it.  I know the feeling of having to start all over again.  It's a strong motivation to keep backups.  It might be worth your time to learn how to create both JSON and ascii file backups with Apps Script API.  I've been doing that for quite a while and one of the nice things about it is that it doesn't create more projects like making copies of the container does.